# How to use tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, tablespaces, transparent-data-encryption

I am trying to implement [Transperent Data Encryption](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e40393/asotrans.htm#ASOAG600).  I am done with setting up the wallet and creating the tablespace.

My doubt is how to specify tablespace so that every object(tables/functions/triggers/etc) is created inside that tablespace.

Can it be done by altering user as below so that every object created by `user1` is automatically created inside the tablespace `securespace`? Assuming the following command does so.

```
ALTER USER "user1" DEFAULT TABLESPACE "securespace" TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP" ACCOUNT UNLOCK ;
```

or do I have to specify `securespace` in every DDL statement?

Comment: Test the `alter` that you think might work?

Comment: Thanks @Philᵀᴹ. In that case, how do I verify if everything is created in the tablespace?

Comment: Create some objects & use the `DBA_OBJECTS` view to see which tablespace they have been created in

Comment: Got it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ, yes, the `alter user` query works as expected, though I had to use `dba_segment` view to see tablespace usage.  Thanks again, though!.